# How to optimize regexp_contains join between two tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Working in BigQuery with the following fact pattern:

1. Table containing 2.5M rows, composed of a string id, string description, and timestamp.
2. Second smaller table with 50 records, string description column is the only field.

Essentially, the code I am working with joins these two tables based on the string description from table 1 by using regexp_contains with the second table. The first table's description field is a description and URL concatenated together.

One of the wild solutions I was thinking of trying is unioning the two tables together and then performing a self join with the same regex_contains criteria, but unsure if that's even worth it? Are there any other "solutions" I haven't considered?

The current join looks like this:

```
table 1 INNER JOIN table 2 ON regexp_contains (field1, field2)
```

After looking at the execution plan, the join is the most expensive aspect of the code, and I've tried finding alternatives to bring the execution/compute time down. I've tried utilize CASE WHEN without declared joins, I've tried using a subquery determining if a match is made, tried using UPPER to reduce the amount of character evaluations. Nothing seems to really improve performance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result so we can better help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your joins are exploding. Since your second table only has 50 records, you could try passing all 50 patterns as one `regex` using `string_agg`.

```
select * 
from t1
where regexp_contains(descr, '(?i)'||(select string_agg(descr,'|') from t2))
```

The other option you could try is a `semi join` using `exists`. For some reason BigQuery doesn't allow this type of join without including an equality operator that involves columns from both the tables. To get around that, we can use a `CTE` to add a constant `id` column in the derived tables.

```
with 
cte1 as (select 1 as dummy, * from t1),

cte2 as (select 1 as dummy, * from t2)

select *
from cte1 a
where exists (select * 
              from cte2 b
              where a.dummy=b.dummy and 
                    regexp_contains(a.descr, '(?i)'||b.descr)
```

Comment: Thanks for these solutions! I'll try the first one here shortly, after I just discovered there are actually 520 total records in the smaller table. 

The second solution doesn't work because of the enforced joins on the IDs that aren't related. I tried exists without that enforced join and it results in even more records.

Comment: Tried out the string_agg function and no changes in execution

Comment: @Tender_Figs How long is it taking to execute?

Comment: @Tender_Figs Sorry I didn't realize you already had an ID column. Could you try the exist solution again after my update?

Comment: Ok, this is an error response I have been given: "LEFT SEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

Comment: And what I have is two CTEs, each of where I impose 1 as dummy... then joining the two CTEs on the respective dummy fields.

Comment: @Tender_Figs That's the same error I received when I tried to join the table on `regexp_contains` only. It let me do the join after I added those dummy columns on each tables and joined on dummy+regexp. No idea why you're getting that error

Comment: Looks like in some instances it can take 5 minutes, which we have a timeout configured with our bigquery project...which I can increase if a solution isn't readily found

Comment: @Tender_Figs Just to rule out any significant penalties due to case-sensitive search, I added in `'(?i)'` to the regex. See if it helps. For the exists based solution, you could try altering the table to add dummy columns and join that way.